# Echo single MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo out one field from my database so I do not want to use a `while` loop.
The database table is called `index` and the field that I want to echo is called `title`.

What is wrong with this code as the output is just blank.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['title'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add LIMIT or check your database against something

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index WHERE id='$someid' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: this may be a no brainer, but do you have values in your table?

Comment: Yes I have added values in the table and added the database connection file.

Comment: @andrewliu: Downvote:You can edit Lion's Answer, right.Why you write the same answer twice in this question.

Comment: its not the same, I'm adding something so he'll have the option?

Answer (score 4):

You're passing a wrong argument to `mysql_fetch_array()`. Modify it as follows.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['title'];
```

---

You need to pass `$result` and not `$sql` with the `mysql_fetch_array()`function.

Comment: This, like all other answers here, fetches a row and not a field.

Comment: That's the responsibility of OP to manage all such code stuffs. I just indicated the exact mistake he did in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row); ///see what you get
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution would be `mysql_result`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM index LIMIT 1');
$field = mysql_result($result, 'title');
```